How to approach classification with many categorical features
I'm new to ML and would like to know more about classification. I have a small dataset of n=600 scored samples and thousands of potential metrics, all categorical (True or False). Basically, I would like to tell which of these thousands of metrics have the best predictive value against the known score so I can use them on an unknown dataset. I'm also thinking of summing up the true values of the good features together to have a single numerical metric that would easily show which samples are the most likely to have high scores (assuming having a true value in each feature correlates with having a higher score)
Oh, and if that helps, I usually code in Python but am also a neophyte when it comes to using GPUs in my scripts, so if you have any advice regarding that, please let me know!
I understand that with this amount of samples it's complicated to build an actual model (especially since score categories have significant size discrepancies), so I am mostly looking to better understand the impact of each feature and how to combine them in a meaningful way.
Thank you!
So far I have been using prior knowledge about the features to arbitrarily select 40 of them without conducting any tests. I have combined them into a single numerical metric by summation on which I performed pearson correlation. Needless to say the values I obtain are quite low (around 0,35 or so) and that becomes way worse when obtained a R2 score following regression against the known scores.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


Basically, I would like to tell which of these thousands of metrics
have the best predictive value against the known score so I can use
them on an unknown dataset

Use logistic regression for that

I'm also thinking of summing up the true values of the good features
together to have a single numerical metric that would easily show
which samples are the most likely to have high scores

After you identified good predictors, you can create an ensemble model of them.

At first glance, your classification problem may seem overwhelming due to the number of features, but you can break it down into several manageable steps.
Step 1: Transform binary data into numerical
If all of your features are categorical with True/False values, they are actually numerical features. You can encode them as binary values, where True = 1 and False = 0. This means your problem is not really a categorical one, but rather a numerical classification problem, which simplifies the modeling process.
Step 2: Reduce the number of features
You have thousands of features, which makes feature selection essential. It might be tempting to use all the available features, but this is the wrong approach. Each additional feature increases the model's complexity, which means it needs more data to learn effectively. Using too many features without significant predictive power will lead to model performance degradation.
How to approach feature selection:

Non-correlated features: Not all features will have a significant
correlation with your target (the output variable). Features that
show no correlation should be discarded.
Correlated features: Features that are highly correlated with each
other bring redundant information to the model, which can introduce
noise, so they should also be removed.
Constant or quasi-constant features: Features that have the same
value for all (or almost all) samples are not useful for the model
and should be removed. Quasi-constant features typically have the
same value for 95-98% of the samples, and they can usually be safely
dropped. However, be cautious in imbalanced datasets, as
quasi-constant features may carry important information in such
cases.
Target Encoding for categorical features: If you have categorical
features with a large number of possible values that cannot be
easily reduced to binary, I recommend using Target Encoding. This
technique can reduce categorical features by encoding them based on
the target variable, even when there are a huge number of
categories. You can use the category_encoders library for this:
https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/targetencoder.html

For these tasks, I recommend using the feature-engine library: https://feature-engine.trainindata.com/en/latest/api_doc/selection/index.html
You can also use VarianceThreshold from scikit-learn to remove constant features:
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold

selector = VarianceThreshold(threshold=0.01)  # Adjust the threshold based on your data
X_reduced = selector.fit_transform(X)

Step 3: Model selection
With 600 samples and thousands of features, tree-based models are better suited than neural networks. Neural networks may struggle to converge well with this amount of data, leading to poor performance.
I recommend trying models like:

XGBoost
LightGBM (if the number of samples is larger)
CatBoost (designed for categorical features, but in your case, they
are already binary)

Tree-based models process features sequentially, and if you set a maximum depth for the tree, it automatically limits the number of features processed. Here is a useful guide for tuning the size of decision trees in XGBoost:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/tune-number-size-decision-trees-xgboost-python
Step 4: Feature importance and further reduction
Once you've trained a preliminary model with XGBoost, you can perform additional feature selection. I recommend using the mlxtend library, which allows for sequential feature selection:
https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/feature_selection/SequentialFeatureSelector
After selecting the most important features, you can use the SHAP library to better understand the impact of each feature on your model's predictions. SHAP allows you to explain how each feature affects model output, both globally and for individual samples:
https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest
Example code using SHAP for feature importance:
import shap

# Train your XGBoost model first
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X)

Step 5: Data Splitting
When splitting your dataset into training and test sets, especially if you have imbalanced classes, it's important to use stratified splitting. This ensures that the proportion of each class in the training and test sets remains consistent, which helps avoid biased model performance. You can achieve this easily in Python using StratifiedKFold or StratifiedShuffleSplit from sklearn.model_selection.
Example code for stratified data splitting:
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

Step 6: Cross-validation
To ensure that your model generalizes well to new data, I recommend using cross-validation. This helps avoid overfitting and provides a more reliable estimate of model performance. For example, you can use StratifiedKFold for cross-validation with imbalanced data:
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, StratifiedKFold

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=skf)
print(f'Cross-Validation Accuracy: {scores.mean()}')

Conclusion
Once you've reduced your feature set and trained your model, you can proceed to final training with the selected features. While tree-based models like XGBoost are a good option, you can also try auto-ML frameworks like Ludwig:
https://ludwig.ai/latest
If you want to go further, you can fine-tune your model's hyperparameters using tools like Hyperopt, Optuna, or Ray. Ray is particularly useful as it can work with multiple optimizers.
For more advanced approaches, consider predicting the uncertainty of your model using TensorFlow Probability. You can also assess the impact of data noise and limited sample size on your uncertainty predictions using Evidential Deep Learning:
https://github.com/aamini/evidential-deep-learning
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toTcf7tZK8c
